# Gstreamer libarary cross-compilation for ARM Cross-compiler toolchain for making an embedded Gstaremer toolchain application

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, gstreamer

I want to write an embedded gstreamer application for an ARM processor. I have a cross-compiler toolchain, but it doesn't have the support of the gstreamer libraries. Since I have not compiled the library for ARM, how can I cross-compile the gstreamer library and link it with the toolchain, so that I can cross-compile a gstreamer application on X86 machine?

Comment: Which toolchain? Have you checked its documentation? Compiling a library and an application using this library is typically covered in the documentation.

Comment: I'm using Code Sourcery toolchain , ok newayz since i was not able to cross-compile the library i got it readymade from a site http://felipec.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/my-arm-development-notes/ now the thing is I'm not able to compile my application using this library , I mean I'm not able to link the library or the headers to this cross-compiler toolchain

Comment: If you want help with linking gstreamer libs to your code, please show what you do and what errors you get.